# discord.js var token unexpected

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

so ive got this code ive been trying to figure out for a couple hours now and no matter what i try i cant figure out what is wrong with my var thing and nothing

```
async run (message, user) 
   var = mentionlycan = message.mentions.users.first()

   var lycanroll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    if (lycanroll < 50)
    guildMember.addRole(role, mentionlycan);

    message.reply(` ${mention} was attacked and converted into a Lycan`)

guildMember.addRole(role);
     if (lycanroll > 50)
     message.reply(`was attacked and they survived. ${mention}.`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the second line.

```
 var = mentionlycan = message.mentions.users.first()
```

You're defining a variable wrong. Change it to:

```
var mentionlycan = message.mentions.users.first();
```

Comment: it moves the error unexpected token up to the 2nd line  now so it is now on ``` var mentionlycan = message.mentions.users.first();```

Comment: its okay i managed to fix it literally missing { after async i wan tto die lmao